# How can I create a third dataframe using matched values from two other dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2.

```
df1

structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), Book = c("BkA", 
"BkA", "BkB", "BkB", "BkB", "BkB", "BkA", "BkA"), Home = c("ATL", 
"ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "SF", "SF"), Away = c("CIN", 
"CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "NY", "NY"), Team = c("ATL", 
"CIN", "ATL", "CIN", "ATL", "CIN", "SF", "NY"), Price = c(-110, 
-110, -110, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105), Points = c(-1.5, 1.5, 
-1.5, 1.5, -2, 2, -2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Book = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Home = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Away = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Team = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Price = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Points = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000024e53738450>, 
class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 8 × 7
 ID Book  Home  Away  Team  Price Points
<dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 BkA   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
2     1 BkA   ATL   CIN   CIN    -110    1.5
3     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
4     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    1.5
5     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   ATL    -105   -2  
6     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    2  
7     2 BkA   SF    NY    SF     -105   -2  
8     2 BkA   SF    NY    NY     -105    2  

df2

structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Book = c("BkC", 
"BkC", "BkC", "BkC", "BkC", "BkC", "BkC", "BkC"), Home = c("ATL", 
"ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF"), Away = c("CIN", 
"CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY"), Team = c("ATL", 
"CIN", "ATL", "CIN", "SF", "NY", "SF", "NY"), Price = c(-110, 
-110, -110, -105, -111, -112, -113, -115), Points = c(-1.5, 1.5, 
-3, 3, -2, 2, -3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Book = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Home = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Away = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Team = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Price = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Points = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000024e48cfcb50>, 
class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 8 × 7
 ID Book  Home  Away  Team  Price Points
<dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
2     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   CIN    -110    1.5
3     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -3  
4     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    3  
5     2 BkC   SF    NY    SF     -111   -2  
6     2 BkC   SF    NY    NY     -112    2  
7     2 BkC   SF    NY    SF     -113   -3  
8     2 BkC   SF    NY    NY     -115    3
```

I would like to create df3 which contains the contents of df1 and df2 if certain conditions are met.

Take for example df1.  The first 2 rows are considered a single baseball game (ID column uniquely identifies each game).

```
1,BkA,ATL,CIN,ATL,-110,-1.5
1,BkA,ATL,CIN,CIN,-110,1.5
```

I would like to look in df2 and see if BkC has matching Points values for the same game (ID column) and same teams (Team column).  There is a match

```
1,BkC,ATL,CIN,ATL,-110,-1.5
1,BkC,ATL,CIN,CIN,-110,1.5
```

If a match is found, I would like to create df3 which contains the rows from df1 and the matched rows from df2.  This is the desired output of df3

```
df3
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), Book = c("BkA", 
"BkA", "BkB", "BkB", "BkB", "BkB", "BkA", "BkA", "BkC", "BkC", 
"BkC", "BkC"), Home = c("ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", 
"SF", "SF", "ATL", "ATL", "SF", "SF"), Away = c("CIN", "CIN", 
"CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "NY", "NY", "CIN", "CIN", "NY", "NY"
), Team = c("ATL", "CIN", "ATL", "CIN", "ATL", "CIN", "SF", "NY", 
"ATL", "CIN", "SF", "NY"), Price = c(-110, -110, -110, -105, 
-105, -105, -105, -105, -110, -110, -111, -112), Points = c(-1.5, 
1.5, -1.5, 1.5, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1.5, 1.5, -2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Book = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Home = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Away = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Team = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Price = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Points = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000024e48cfcd30>, 
class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 12 × 7
  ID Book  Home  Away  Team  Price Points
<dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 BkA   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
2     1 BkA   ATL   CIN   CIN    -110    1.5
3     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
4     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    1.5
5     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   ATL    -105   -2  
6     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    2  
7     2 BkA   SF    NY    SF     -105   -2  
8     2 BkA   SF    NY    NY     -105    2  
9     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
10     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   CIN    -110    1.5
11     2 BkC   SF    NY    SF     -111   -2  
12     2 BkC   SF    NY    NY     -112    2
```

I am fairly confident that it is possible but I am struggling with the syntax.

***Using the suggestion from @Akrun below***

```
rows_upsert(df1, df2, by = c("ID",  "Home", "Away", "Price", "Points"))
```

This is what I get which is not the same desired output as df3

```
# A tibble: 14 × 7
  ID Book  Home  Away  Team  Price Points
<dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
2     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   CIN    -110    1.5
3     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -1.5
4     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    1.5
5     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   ATL    -105   -2  
6     1 BkB   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    2  
7     2 BkA   SF    NY    SF     -105   -2  
8     2 BkA   SF    NY    NY     -105    2  
9     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   ATL    -110   -3  
10     1 BkC   ATL   CIN   CIN    -105    3  
11     2 BkC   SF    NY    SF     -111   -2  
12     2 BkC   SF    NY    NY     -112    2  
13     2 BkC   SF    NY    SF     -113   -3  
14     2 BkC   SF    NY    NY     -115    3
```

Comment: Try with `rows_upsert` i.e `rows_upsert(df1, df2, by = c("ID",  "Home", "Away", "Price", "Points"))`

Comment: Hi @Akrun.  I tried your suggestion but it doesn't match up with df3 in the original post.  I will update my original post with the output of rows_upsert.

Comment: It seems like dplyr::intersect could somehow do this.  If I use intersect(df1$Points, df2$Points) the common values are returned but not the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. First create another dataframe then add it back into df1 with a join.

```
test <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c(Book,Price)) %>%  
  dplyr::intersect(df2 %>% dplyr::select(!c(Book,Price)) ) %>% 
  mutate(Book='BkC')
out <- df1 %>% full_join(test)
```

Now to get those prices back, bit of a hack but seems to work.

```
    out %>% left_join(df2 %>% rename(price=Price)) %>% 
    mutate(Price=ifelse(is.na(price),Price,price))%>% 
    select(-price)
```

Comment: If you need it you'll have to figure out how to get the price back into `out`

Comment: Oh man, this works well except for the Price not showing.  As you already stated.

Comment: @ Aaron Morris, give that a try! There may be more succinct ways but sometimes getting started is the hardest part

Comment: You're a genius @dandrews!  Funny how it took going around the elbow twice to get to the forearm.  Let me test this in my production dataset.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, bit of a workaround but seems to work. If it solved your problem please vote up the answer...that's all I get for a cookie for working on your problems instead of mine!

Comment: I just used your final edit, no need for the interim, I just forgot to remove the working column `price` thanks for catching that